# Batch filling multiple forms using data from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, batch

I have an excel file which contains many rows of data, each row has columns like last name, first name, gender etc. I would like to batch fill these data into multiple forms of different types. Basically what I am doing is trying to simplify the HR process of new hire documents. So there are word forms and pdf forms.

Comment: Mail Merge might be worth investigating for Word. I think you should be able to pull data from Excel, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

For word documents you can use a mail merge:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx

I'm not sure about PDFs, but you could at least convert the word documents into PDFs if that made sense for your business process.

If you have a developer handy, this could be a simple Ruby on Rails or Django app to replace the Excel spreadsheet. It would be easier to do this with code.

Answer (score 0):

Mail merge is the way to go, I do it all the time.  However, you may need to add some switches to the merge fields if you have specialized formatting in Excel (it doesn't carry over to Word).  If need be, here's how you do it:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/format-merged-data-HP005187180.aspx